# How do I count text lines?

Tags: command-line

How do I count how many lines are in text file.
e.g :

```
command file.txt
```

Note, I want to only count the non-empty lines (lines without counting white space and tabs)?.

Comment: See [count (non-blank) lines-of-code in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114814/count-non-blank-lines-of-code-in-bash)

Comment: The question is not well-defined: is a line with only whitespace (spaces and TAB) considered empty?

Comment: **Close voters**: Question edited after @Rmano's clarification according to [his comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/598643/how-do-i-count-text-lines#comment834347_598643) by OP. So please don't vote to close as Unclear

Comment: @KasiyA it's still unclear. I don't understand if the OP wants to count sa line with only whitespace (spaces, tabs, `\r`) or skip them. The current answers all count lines with spaces and only skip empty ones.

Comment: @terdon OP DON'T want to counting the blank-lines (including empty-lines(`\r` or `\n`), lines-with-only-tabs and lines-with-only-spaces) and want to skip them as I think and [answered](http://askubuntu.com/a/598700/283843) according to what I understood.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The above answer are correct but slightly different, you can use the `grep` to for easier code such `grep -vc '^$' file.txt`

For example(A):file.txt

```
$grep -vc '^$' file.txt

1    First line         #This is two tabs to comment.
2    
4
3    Fourth line        #Another two tabs to comment.

$2
```

For example(B):file.txt

```
$sed '/^$/d' file.txt | wc -l

1    First line         #This is two tabs to comment.
2    
4
3    Fourth line        #Another two tabs to comment.

$4
```

Notice the result is 4! when we want to expect only two. but this counts the tabs in between the content and comment as well.

Notice the counts from 0 and counts from 1 its different from the grep to the sed as I remember for more details search for grep or sed.

Comment: Both of your examples will count the empty lines, but OP requested a command to count everything BUT the empty lines

Comment: Actually I'm wrong, the `sed` option is actually correct, but the `grep` one is not

Comment: Being only partially correct I downvoted the answer, drop me a comment when you have fixed it so i can remove my downvote

Comment: @kos I am quite sure, you notice how sort of vague the question is ?

Comment: "The above answer are correct but slightly different, you can use the `grep` to for easier code such `grep -c '^$' file.txt`", so you're suggesting to use this command to "only count the non-empty lines", which is OP's request: even tough it's not clear whether OP needs a command to match only empty lines or to match empty lines and lines containing whitespaces, tabs etc, `grep -c '^$' file.txt` will just count the empty lines, not the non-empty lines nor the empty lines and the lines containing whitespaces, tabs etc, so the command is wrong in any case

Comment: Plus I see you actually edited (after my comment) the `grep` line in the snippet adding the `-v` option, so it looks like you realized your mistake already, please edit the `grep` line in the first sentence as well then drop me another comment and i'll remove my downvote

Comment: @kos, You were right in the first place, Thank you. I haven't slept in over 36 hours, I guess its time for bed!

Comment: Yep :) un-downvoted and upvoted

Answer (score 12):

Try `sed`:

```
sed '/^$/d' file.txt | wc -l
```

If you have any lines containing only spaces or tabs and if you want to ignore them as well from count:

```
sed '/^[[:blank:]]*$/d' file.txt | wc -l
```

Comment: I would use `^\s*$` to also take into account lines only containing tab or spaces.

Comment: @SylvainPineau: Added..

Comment: I agree that it was not clear from OP's question, but text with spaces/tab can alter the expected result, +1.

Answer (score 3):

Using `grep`:

```
grep -vc '^$' file  # or
grep -vc '^\s*$' file
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
grep -cve '^\s*$' file.txt
```

If you need a command for that, just paste the following lines into your `.bashrc` and restart your shell session or open a new terminal:

```
count_lines()
{
    grep -cve '^\s*$' $1
}
```

Example:

```
count_lines file.txt
42
```

Answer (score 2):

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```bsh
awk 'NF{++count} END{print count}' file
```

#### Explanation:

The `NF` indicates the total number of fields, and hence this prints **only non-blank lines**, since in non-blank lines `NF` is greater than `0` and evaluates to true. So increment the *count* flag when awk found a non-blank lines and *print* the latest value of *count* flag at the end by `END{print count}`.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: you can just add the `c` option to `grep` instead of piping everything to `wc`, see @muru's answer for a more compact version

---

With `grep`:

```
grep -v '^$' file.txt | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Perl solution

Perl can do that. In general counting lines works as so:

```
$ perl -ne 'END{print $.}' input.txt
```

If we want to exclude all empty lines, we'll do something like this:

```
$ perl -ne '$c+=1 if not /^$|^\s+$/;END{print $c}' input.txt
```

Let's say we have input file like this

```
$ cat -n input.txt
     1  Cat; Dog; Squirrel
     2  ORGANISM Animalus terrus
     3  
     4  Sequence: ACGTACGTACGTACGTACGTACGTACGTACGTACGTACGTACGTACGT
     5
```

There's 5 lines total, 2 empty lines. The command we have would output:

```
$ perl -ne '$c+=1 if not /^$|^\s+$/;END{print $c}' input.txt                                                             
3
```

---

#### Multi-file improvement

This works well for a single file. If we want to have it working on multiple files, we can do something like this:

```
$ perl -ne '$c+=1 if not /^$|^\s+$/;printf("%d %s\n",$c,$ARGV) and $c=0 if eof' input.txt /etc/passwd                    
3 input.txt
52 /etc/passwd
```