# How to count number of process instances with bash?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Writing

```
ps aux | awk '{print $11}'
```

Gives me all the process instances, but how do I count them, is there a command that does that?

Comment: In future, if you want to count number of any output, just pipe it to the wc -l command. Like this, `command | wc -l` It will give you the count.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As `ps aux` prints information about one process per line (including a headline, which can be disabled with the `--no-heading` option).

Therefore you can easily count the processes by simply counting the lines of this output, using `wc`:

```
ps aux --no-heading | wc -l
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `awk`:

```
ps aux --no-heading | awk 'END {print NR}'
```

and if you want to count an specific user's process:

```
ps -u ravexina -f --no-header | wc -l
```

As an alternative you can check `/proc` filesystem yourself:

```
ls /proc | grep ^[1-9] -c
```

or

```
ls -d /proc/[1-9]* | wc -l
```

Comment: @terdon This is the proc filesystem, not some user-supplied data. Any file at the root of the proc filesystem whose name starts with a digit is a subdirectory whose name is a PID and whose content is information about the process with this PID. And all the files in this hierarchy are “tame”, containing only ASCII alphanumerics and `_` and non-leading `-` (also a few more punctuation characters outside the PID directories, but none that would cause problems in shells).

Comment: @Gilles OK, as I said, the chances of a newline-name there are very small, but can you really be 100% sure that any and all numerical file names in `/proc` will always be current PIDs? Or, more relevantly, that if a numerical file name is found in `/proc` then you can be certain it will also be listed in `ps`?

Comment: @terdon 1. Yes: Linux kernel maintainers take backward compatibility seriously, and since many people have made this assumption, they'll keep guaranteeing it. 2. Yes, because that's how `ps` gathers its information (try `strace ps`).

Comment: @Gilles fair enough, I thought it was looking at a file in /proc, I hadn't realized it just went through the files directly. Thanks for the correction. My apologies for talking nonsense Ravexina.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers already have mentioned that `ps aux` adds a header, so you need `--no-heading` option as well.  What else we can do is that we can use `pgrep` command for obtaining process PIDs and then counting those.

Basically we can do,

```
pgrep '^.*$' | awk 'END{print NR}'
```

The trick here is that `END{}` code block is always executed after processing file,stdin, or pipeline is done, and NR remains unchanged, which is the "number of records" or number of lines if that's only one file or pipeline. As for `pgrep`, we're just matching any process with `^.*$` regular expression, thus getting list of all PIDs.

And for counting lines you can take literally any method from [How do I count text lines?](https://askubuntu.com/q/598643/295286) question, it doesn't only have to be `awk`.

Comment: +1 the good thing about this answer if that `pgrep` does not include itself to the list ;)